# "Best" Definition of Complex Argument

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, definition

Let $z = a + bi \in \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$. Some books define the argument of $z$ as the angle between the vector $z$ and the abscissa axis, in the counter-clockwise. So, $\arg \left( z \right) \in [0,2\pi)$.

But in other books, the argument of $z$ is the lower angle between the vector $z$ and the abscissa axis. So $\arg \left( z \right) \in (- \pi , \pi]$. When the counter-clockwise, $\arg(z) \geq 0$. When clockwise, $\arg(z) < 0$.

My first question: which is the "best" definition? Which of them is the "less problematic" definition of the argument of a complex number?

My second question: is there a formula for the argument of a complex number? In each case?

Comment: Argument needs to be in a half open interval, such as $~[0,2\pi),~$ or $~(-\pi,2\pi].~$  My (subjective) feeling as to *best* is that it depends on the problem that you are trying to solve.  This makes things challenging for an author, because there does seem to be an advantage in choosing a specific range to denote the *principal argument*, and sticking with it throughout the book.  When examining the $~n~$ distinct roots of $~z^n = 1,~$ the $~[0,2\pi),~$ range seems to be easier for me to *understand*.  ...see next comment

Comment: On the other hand, when using complex analysis to compute (for example) $~\cos(2\pi/5),~$ by converting $~z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1 = 0~$ via $~w = [z + (1/z)],~$ and grappling with $~|z| = 1 \implies (1/z) = \overline{z},~$ the $~(-\pi,\pi],~$ range simply *feels* more natural to me.

Comment: See [principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) and [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: Typing $[0,2\pi)$ is one character shorter than $(-\pi,\pi]$ which is the only meaningful difference I can find between them.

Comment: There are very meaningful differences; they define entirely different logarithms, and my favourite integration technique completely relies on this fact. If I want a logarithm whose cut lies on $[0,\infty)$, my only option is to use the $[0,2\pi)$ argument (or a $[2\pi,4\pi)$ argument, etc)

Comment: We can use completely arbitrary definitions of argument in the range $(a,a+2\pi]$ or $[a,a+2\pi)$, where $a$ is any real number at all

Comment: @CyclotomicField Don't both expressions require exactly 6 characters?

Comment: @user2661923 as rendered there are only 6 characters but when you type the markup we can see that [0,2\pi) is 8 characters while (-\pi,\pi] is 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim this is the "best" definition of argument but here is one approach.

Recall that any $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ can be expressed as
$$w=|w|e^{i\theta}$$
for some $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, where $|w|=\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}^2(w) +\operatorname{Im}^2(w)}$.

1. The set
   $$\operatorname{Arg}_w:=\{\theta\in\mathbb{R}: w=|w|e^{i\theta}\}$$
   is the called the set of ***arguments*** of $w$. It is easy to check that if $\theta_1,\theta_2\in\operatorname{Arg}_w$, then $\theta_1-\theta_2\in 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$. One may think of the argument as a relation $\operatorname{Arg}=\{(w,\theta)\in(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb{R}:w=|w|e^{i\theta}\}$.
2. Give $\theta_0$, for any $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, there is a unique $\theta_w\in[\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi)\cap\operatorname{Arg}_w$. The map $\operatorname{arg}_{\theta_0}:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow[\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi)$ given by $w\mapsto\theta_w$ is called a ***branch*** of the argument.

Once argument is defined, it is possible to extend the notion of Logarithm to the complex plane. This is one way to do it:

3. The relation  $\operatorname{Log}$ from $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $(w,z)\in \operatorname{Log}$ iff $e^z=w$ is called ***logarithm***. For $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, the set $\operatorname{Log}_w=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: (w,z)\in\operatorname{Log}\}$ is called the set of logarithms of $w$. It is easy to check that
   $$\operatorname{Log}_w =\{ \ln|w|+i\theta:\theta\in\operatorname{Arg}_w\}$$
   where $\ln:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the natural logarithm function from Calculus or Real analysis.
4. Selecting a brach $\theta_0$ of $\operatorname{Arg}$ yields a function $\log_{\theta_0}:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, given as $w\mapsto \ln|w|+i\operatorname{arg}_{\theta_0}(w)$, where $\theta\in[\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi)$. The map $\log_{\theta_0}$ is called a ***branch*** of logarithm.